# Save another's stream with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, p2p, webrtc

We have 2 users(user1 and user2) and they are connected to each other by P2P.
Is it possible to save video/audio stream from user1 on computer user2?

Answer (score 0):

You can record stream using [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/). You can find many demos and stuff available [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC).

*P.S. currently RecordRTC is incapable to record remote audio; see an experimental demo [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/demos/remote-stream-recording.html).*